# How to use knockout's style binding when using recursive models

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using Knockout 3.0.0 and I am working with a nested model: A shape can contain an arbitrary number of other shapes.

This is example data:

```
var process =
{
"type": "process",
"id": "singletask",
"name": "Default Process",
"children": [
    {"type": "task",
     "id": "Task_1",
     "name": "Task 1",
     "bounds": {
        "x": "435.0",
        "y": "175.0",
        "height": "50.0",
        "width": "110.0"
      },
      "children": []
    }
    ]
};
```

I construct the view model like follows:

```
function getBounds(bounds) {
    var res = {
                  "x": ko.observable(bounds.x),
                  "y": ko.observable(bounds.y),
                  "height": ko.observable(bounds.height),
                  "width": ko.observable(bounds.width)
             }
    return res;
}

/* recursively construct view model out of JSON data */
function getPartOfViewModel(data) {
    var children= [];
    $.each(data.children, function(i, e) {
        var res = getPartOfViewModel(e);
        children.push(res);
    });
    var res = {
        "type": ko.observable(data.type),
        "template": data.type + "-template",
        "id": ko.observable(data.type),
        "name": ko.observable(data.type),
        "children": children
    }

    // not all elements have bounds
    if (data.bounds) {
        $.extend(res, {"bounds":getBounds(data.bounds)});
    }
    return res;
}

var viewModel = getPartOfViewModel(process);
```

I assume that there is something wrong as I cannot use "this", when trying to create computed entries. (This seems to be a separate question)

The HTML is pretty straightforward

```
<div data-bind="foreach: $data.children" class="drawingarea">
    <div data-bind="template: { name: $data.template, data: $data }"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="task-template">
    <div data-bind="css: type, style: {left: $data.bounds.x + 'px', top: bounds.top + 'px', height: $data.bounds.height + 'px', width: $data.bounds.width + 'px'}">
        <span data-bind="text: $data.bounds.x"></span>/<span data-bind="text: $data.bounds.y"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data.bounds.height"></span>/<span data-bind="text: $data.bounds.width"></span>
    </div>
</script>
```

The issue is that the rendered shape contains the text `435.0/175.0 50.0/110.0` but doesn't have the right position. What am I doing wrong?

Full example at: http://jsbin.com/robukuvu/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/robukuvu/16)***

Your code is fine you just need two changes:

1. ***First,*** for css property `top` you fogot to add `$data` and replace `top` with `y`. so it should be top: `$data.bounds.y() + 'px'`
2. ***Second,*** your objects `x`, `y`, `height`, `width` they are all observables objects then in your binding no need to use `()` and also no need for `+ 'px'`

So final correct HTML code:

```
<div data-bind="css: type, style: {left: $data.bounds.x, top: $data.bounds.y, height: $data.bounds.height, width: $data.bounds.width}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data-bind="style: {left: $data.bounds.x() + 'px', top: $data.bounds.y() + 'px', height: $data.bounds.height() + 'px', width: $data.bounds.width() + 'px'}"
```

**1.**
In the `top` part, you missed the `$data` prefix.

**2.**
You don't have a `top` field in your `bounds` structure, you actually named it `y` in your `getBounds()` function.

**3.**
Since you're using observables, Knockout is able to handle `$data.bounds.x` (for example) without the need to invoke the observable, but since you're concatenating 'px' to it, it tries to evaluate the expression as a whole and the result is actually the 'px' appended to the observable function.

That's why you need `$data.bounds.x() + 'px'` instead of `$data.bounds.x + 'px'`.